# Glide takes long time before displaying large images

Tags: android, android-glide

I am trying to load images (around 5mb each) into `ImageView`'s of size 45x45 dp in a RecyclerView. Even though original image is large, doesn't Glide load a smaller version of it because target ImageView is small? So, I expect Glide to load images in just a few seconds with an average internet speed. But, it takes like 20 seconds. What is the problem?

Images are stored in firebase storage.

Glide code :

```
Glide.with(context).load(firebaseStorageUrl).into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Glide needs to load the full image from the internet before it can resize it. So the download takes a long time the first time. Afterwards it can use the small image from the cahe it created if you have caching activated.

Comment: so having image files in server larger than 1mb is just wrong ?

Comment: It really depends what you plan to do with them. If you dont need the high resolution ever, do not store it. But if you need the high-res versions for something else, you should also add small versions in another folder or with a prefix like "thumb_"

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't want to load smaller files, I recommend using a [Gif-drawable](https://github.com/koral--/android-gif-drawable) library for loading large images from Glide into GifDrawable(works as an ImageView).

It can load files more than 100MB very fast. It works with plain JPG, PNG and BMP too. If these are GIFs, it plays without any delay or freeze.

> If drawables declared by android:src and/or android:background are GIF files then they will be automatically recognized as GifDrawables and animated. If given drawable is not a GIF then mentioned Views work like plain ImageView and ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

`Glide` downloads the image first, and then you have methods to retrieve the image as bitmap to resize and compress the image. However, that won't solve your problem . Possibly there are two solutions for this:

1. Keep a low sized image in the server.
2. Use a File downloader library, which helps to download images serially and asynchronously as a queue, which would help to download the file quick. [FileDownloader](https://github.com/lingochamp/FileDownloader) library is a good option for this.

Answer (score -1):

Use Override in Glide for load image faster.

Comment: Can you explain more detail?